# Drop single NA values from list columns

Tags: r

I am wanting to drop the individual NA values from this list so I can apply DTW Hierarchical clustering. Please see attached photos for what we want vs what we have. Most of the literature I have looked at omits the entire row/column with NA values e.g. na.omit. Thanks

[With NA's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ARr.png)

[Without NA's (what we want for OUR values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hYgm.png)

Comment: use lapply(your_list,na.omit)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
new_list <- lapply(list.tdf, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```